# Store in cache a node.js variable

Tags: node.js

I'm trying store in cache (with the `memory-cache` library for node.js), for some reason the callback always return null in the `newResult` variable. What I doing wrong?

```
var getMapping = function(callback){
    if( cache.get("mapping") == null ){
      var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
      fs.readFile('flow.xml', function(err, data) {
          parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            var jsonFile = JSON.stringify(result);
            var newResult = result = jsonFile;
            callback( newResult );
          });
      });
    } else{
      callback( cache.get("mapping") );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to break this down a bit.  What's in `data`?  What's in `result`?  I don't see where you are putting anything in your cache.

Comment: why are you using this var newResult = result = jsonFile? it doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: The newResult doesnt should be null only if your xml file is empty or a error ocurred in the process. You can verify the file too and check if the file is a correct xml file.

Comment: @Pedro lol sorry about that. I was messing around with the code with test purposes. Must be without the = result, only var newResult = jsonFIle; in some level of my coding activity I was using result as the parameter for my callback.

Comment: @Brad you right. Was a stupid error, after messing my code, I forgot the cache.put and I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store in cache you need use the method `.put` with `cache.put(key, value)`.
Try with the follow code:

```
var getMapping = function(callback){
    if( cache.get("mapping") == null ){
      var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
      fs.readFile('flow.xml', function(err, data) {
          parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            var jsonFile = JSON.stringify(result);
            var newResult = result = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
            cache.put("mapping", newResult);
            callback( newResult );
          });
      });
    } else{
      callback( cache.get("mapping") );
    }
}
```